# Converting "NA" within a .csv file that has characters in the columns

Tags: r, csv, na

I am trying to format my data to be used in a multi-state model (program MARK).  My `.csv` file has birds detected at site "R" at a specific date and time. So, I need the `NA` within the columns to be replaced with `0` for not detected at that date and time.

```r
REEDoutput.data <- read.csv("REEDoutput.data.csv", header=TRUE)
```

Re-shape data table for MARK(TEST)

```r
junk <- melt(REEDoutput.data, id.var = c("id", "ts"), measure.var = "num.det")

y <- cast(junk,id ~ts)
y[is.na(y)] <- 0
```

Warning messages are:

> 1. In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
>    invalid factor level, NA generated
> 2. In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
>    invalid factor level, NA generated

I tried:

```r
REEDoutput.data <- read.csv("REEDoutput.data.csv", na.strings = "NA", 
                            header = TRUE)
```

```r
REEDoutput.data <- read.csv("REEDoutput.data.csv",  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                            na.strings = "NA", header = TRUE)
```

```r
REEDoutput.data <- read.csv("REEDoutput.data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                            header = TRUE)
```

All of which still give me the warning message

Comment: If you have a character "NA" string, use the `na.strings= "NA"` in the `read.csv`

Comment: Also, use the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `read.csv` to avoid having `factor` columns as `factor` columns require a `level` 0 specified before you are converting some values to 0 (in case it is not there)

Comment: Neither of these worked, please see my post for the code example.  Can I add my data as an attachment on this site?

Comment: Yes, without a dput output, of a small dataset, we cannot be sure about the structure of your dataset. i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(REEDoutput.data)))` and paste the output in your post

Comment: Also, if you are using `data.table`, it has `dcast/melt` functions.  Use that for doing the reshaping

Comment: @-akrun structure(list(X = 1:6, ts = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "5/28/2014 6:00", class = "factor"), id = c(58L, 
60L, 64L, 68L, 79L, 95L), num.det = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "R", class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", "ts", 
"id", "num.det"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Is it the structure of original data or the transformed one?

Comment: @akrun: That is the structure of the original .csv I read into R before using melt function to reshape.